# Qué hago con él o qué hacer con él

Tags: aspecto-gramatical

En una película española llamada "Contratiempo" (España) vi un siguiente diálogo:

-Lo mejor es que yo me quede aquí para pedir ayuda, ¿vale? Y que tú te ocupes del cuerpo.
-¿Qué hago con él?

Por qué no fue usado "hacer", en la forma infinitiva? Por supuesto, entiendo lo que significa, pero no entiendo gramaticalmente.

P.s. Por adelantado agradezco si corrijan errores en mi letra en tal caso si haya algunos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el diálogo citado la persona está preguntando qué debe hacer con el cuerpo:

- Lo mejor es que tú te ocupes del cuerpo.
- ¿Y qué hago (yo) con él?

En cambio, la pregunta en infinitivo:

- ¿Qué hacer con él?

no tiene sujeto y se interpreta como impersonal. Podría usarse como una reflexión, por ejemplo en la escritura de un diario personal:

- Ahora que me habían encargado ocuparme del cuerpo, ¿qué hacer con él?

En [su página](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Infinitivo%20-%20otros%20usos.htm) sobre usos del infinitivo, Justo Fernández López dice:

> INFINITIVO EN ORACIONES INTERROGATIVAS DIRECTAS PARCIALES
>
> En las interrogativas directas parciales el infinitivo suele presentar la incertidumbre o la indecisión ante alguna actuación futura que se considera problemática o introducir preguntas retóricas.
>
> ¿Qué hacer frente a la crisis?
>
> ¿Cómo saber si alguien te quiere de verdad?
>
> ¿A quién dirigirse para resolver este problema?
>
> ¿Y qué decir de los recortes que ha hecho el Gobierno?
>
> ¿Por qué dedicar tanto tiempo a un asunto tan nimio?
>
> ¿Por qué no esperar a que bajen los precios de los pisos?

Claramente, en un diálogo no puede haber una pregunta retórica, sino que la persona espera una respuesta a su pregunta personalizada, por ejemplo:

- ¿Qué hago con el cuerpo?
- Deshazte de él.